# How to return state of Redux reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

For redux reducer step :
What if I only want to change one single property of initial_state. For example:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  signInInfo: {
    signin: false,
     name: "",
      email: "",
     ...
  },
  changePassword: {
    status: false,
     ...
  }
  ...
};
```

Here I only want to set `signInInfo.signin` as `true`, currently , the only way I know is to input a complete  "signInInfo" like :

```
case SIGNIN_USER:
    return { ...state, signInInfo: action.payload.data };
```

`action.payload.data` is like:

```
{
   signin: true,
   name: "Qing",
   email : ...
}
```

And another question is what if I want to set `signInInfo.signin` as `false`  and meanwhile also need to change `changePassword.status` from `false` to `true`. 
What should I do? Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fairly simple (both questions):

```
case SIGNIN_USER: return {
    ...state,
    signInInfo: {
      ...state.signInInfo,
      signin: action.payload.signin
    },
    changePassword: {
      ...state.changePassword,
      status: true
    }
  };
```

Comment: I encountered a new problem:  if there is an object array in the state, and I only want to set like arr[0].flag to true, what should I do? I just don't know how to represent the arr in that kind of expression shown above. Thank you!

Comment: `return [{...state[0], flag: action.payload}, ...state.slice(1)];` https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos-with-undo/src/reducers/todos.js#L33 http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html